# Virtual Box startup error for Lubuntu - kernel panic not syncing

Tags: 16.04, kernel, virtualbox, lubuntu

I am trying to boot up `Lubuntu` on `virtualbox` to obtain `OpenFOAM` software as indicated @ [Using OpenFOAM in VirtualBox](http://www.ara.bme.hu/~hernadi/OpenFOAM/virtualbox.html?fbclid=IwAR15SBzap_I1f1xhvaoxMRAYfZQ8rhtzqJwfs-WGyEQTMLVAA4rQIUqs8mE) .

I have `ubuntu 16.04 LTS` OS. I receive the `kernel panic` error message on startup as shown in the image below.

[image]

Can anyone advise how to solve this?

Comment: A couple of questions which will seem unrelated to your question.  1)  This for for school?  2)  Do you use Ubuntu, or are you more comfortable with Windows?  3)  Have you installed a VBox machine before?  --  I am asking because limiting yourself to a 32bit version of Ubuntu packaged for you may be difficult to fix - however openFOAM (version 6) is available for Ubuntu, [here](https://openfoam.org/download/6-ubuntu/)

Comment: Its for research. I use ubuntu. This is my first time installing virtualbox. I will checkout the link you gave.

Comment: K - My suggestion would be to abandon the effort to try to get a working 32 bit install of Ubuntu going in a VM, and either use a 64 bit in a VM with a regular install from iso, or adding the PPA that openFOAM developed and installing directly on your machine.